# JSON parse error from Request

Tags: java, json, exception, gson

I am trying to parse JSON but it's not working. Example JSON:

```
{
    "Rpts": {
        "am": [
            {
                "rf":"1",
                "nm":"NS",
                "in":"100.200.210.209",
                "tn":"8080"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Extracting JSON like this:

```
Rpts dem=gsonReq.fromJson(responseJson, Rpts.class);
```

**My Rptsclass:**

```
public class Rpts
{

private AMS am;

    public AMS getAm() {
        return am;
    }

    public void setAm(AMS am) {
        this.am = am;
    }
}
```

**My AMS class:**

```
public class AMS
{
private String rf;
private String nm;
private String in;
private String tn;
public String getRf() {
        return rf;
    }

    public void setRf(String rf) {
        this.rf = rf;
    }

    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }

    public void setNm(String nm) {
        this.nm = nm;
    }

    public String getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public void setIn(String in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public String getTn() {
        return tn;
    }

    public void setTn(String tn) {
        this.tn = tn;
    }
}
```

The parsing is throwing exception everytime. 
Please guide..

Comment: What exception? On which line?

Comment: Please add  the stacktrace.

Comment: I think 'am' must be a List<AMS>.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons pls have a look at the answer, if it solve your purpose.

Comment: @ankur-singhal pls see my comment..Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON, `Rpts` contains an array of `am`...

So your java class should be:

```
public class Rpts {
    private Collection<AMS> am;
    public Collection<AMS> getAm() {
        return am;
    }
    public void setAm(Collection<AMS> am) {
        this.am = am;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the variable name be am or ams ?

Comment: dem.getAm().get(0).getRf() is null. It's throwing NULL Pointer everytime.

Comment: If you rename `am` to `ams` in the Java class, you must also rename it in your JSON.

Comment: Does AMS has any restriction. ? Or it can be any name.. My AMS class contains only getter and setter..... But problem is that Rpts class setter is not getting invoked even once.. Hence the lsit does not contain nay object.

Comment: Have a look at Gson doc (https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support). The name of your fields will be used in the JSON. But not the name of the Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

**RPTS class**

```
public class Rpts {

    private List<AMS> am;

    /**
     * @return the am
     */
    public List<AMS> getAm() {
        return am;
    }

    /**
     * @param am the am to set
     */
    public void setAm(List<AMS> am) {
        this.am = am;
    }
}
```

Json Modified - removed `{"Rpts":` from starting and `}` from end

**Test class**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"am\": [{\"rf\":\"1\",\"nm\":\"NS\",\"in\":\"100.200.210.209\",\"tn\":\"8080\"}]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Rpts rpts = new Rpts();
        try {
            rpts = mapper.readValue(json, Rpts.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(rpts.getAm().get(0).getRf());
        System.out.println(rpts.getAm().get(0).getNm());
    }
```

**output**

```
1
NS
```

Comment: But the list is not containing any object. Everytime it's throwing NULL. dem.getAm().get(0).getRf() is null. It's throwing NULL Pointer everytime

Comment: @AngelsandDemons output also added, no exception

Comment: Well I don't know but at my end it's still null. having a hard time figuring out why even after parsing the json correctly, the get method is returning null

Comment: @AngelsandDemons i will suggest you to post complete code then.